# Error "invalid array length" when importing JSDOM in enzyme.config.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

I've migrated a React codebase to Typescript and I'm having issues to set up Jest.

When I try to run a jest test against a *.test.tsx or .test.jsx file I get the following error:

```js
 RangeError: Invalid array length

       6 | 
    >  7 | const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
         |         ^
```

Here's my jest.config.js:

```js
var tsJesUtils = require('ts-jest/utils');
var pathsToModuleNameMapper = tsJesUtils.pathsToModuleNameMapper;

var tsConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
var compilerOptions = tsConfig.compilerOptions;

module.exports = {
    roots: ["<rootDir>/src/global/ts", "<rootDir>/__tests__"],
    preset: "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts",
    moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/src/global/ts/' }),
    globals: {
      "ts-jest": {
        diagnostics: {
          warnOnly: true
        }
      },
    },

    transformIgnorePatterns: [
            "node_modules/react-jsx-parser"
    ],

    // Setup Enzyme
    snapshotSerializers: ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/__tests__/enzyme.config.js"],

    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageReporters: [
            "text",
            "json",
            "html"
    ],
};
```

And here's my enzyme.config.json file:

```js
import "raf/polyfill";
import { configure, mount, shallow, render } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import React from 'react';

const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const dom = new JSDOM('');

configure( { adapter: new Adapter() } );
```

Anybody ever had this issue and would have a solution for it?

I'm using Enzyme, Jest and JSDOM, all the latest version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being caused because JSDOM is using ES6+ features (in this particular case, using Set()) but my Typescript compiler was using the default output (ES5), which does not have Set.

So the solution is to change the target in tsconfig.json from "es5" to "es6" onwards.